# AngularFire2 vs Firebase JS

Tags: angularjs, angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm finding the AngularFire2 library to be poorly documented and very hard to use. I have an angular2 app and was wondering if someone could help me clear up the pros/cons of just using the vanilla JS Firebase code rather than angularfire2? Does using the vanilla JS version kill off angular2 functionality that I may be using? I'm confused as to why use one over the other, personally the vanilla JS one is waaaay better documented and feature rich, I can't even see how to Signup Users in AngularFire2, it doesn't have any UI elements and observables are doing my head in!

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla version directly. Even with observables - observable and promises work well together. For example:

```
Observable.of(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
  .switchMap(o => firebase.app().auth().signInWithPopup(o))
  .subscribe()
```

Main advantage of AngularFire2 are head-hurting observables (; I suggest you learn rxjs and start using them over promises. I am using vanilla JS SDK, however, I've created `refObservable` based on what AngularFire2 does with [FirebaseObservables](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/src/database). It's simpler, but enough for my needs:

```
export function refObservable(ref): Observable<firebase.database.DataSnapshot> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    let fn;
    try {
      fn = ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        observer.next(unwrapSnapshot(snapshot));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      observer.error(error);
    }
    return () => ref.off('value', fn);
  });
};
```

where `unwrapSnapshot(snapshot)` is simple function that checks snapshot and returns appropriate result (array, object, string, etc...). I use it for reading data from firebase. Create/Update/Delete operations I do directly:

```
Observable.of(checkUserPermission())
  .switchMap(() => {
    return firebase.database().ref('what/ever').remove();
  });
```

It's similar with other modules - storage, messaging, auth... I prefer Firebase SDK over AngularFire2. I also find it easier to use in service/web workers.

- If you already know vanilla sdk, stick with it.
- If you only need database read/write and basic authentication use AngularFire2 it's simpler.
- If you need more control over firebase features use JS SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been trying to get my head around rxJS - however I am struggling with some "concepts" in more advanced uses, Specifically when using Observables in services.

`getUser(){
  return this.getAuth().switchMap((auth) => {
    return this.af.database.object("users/"+auth.uid+"/public");
  });

}

getAuth(){
  return this.af.auth.map((auth) => {return auth});
}`

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve from a comment. Post another question about your problem. As for RxJS, yes it can be overwhelming when you start. Just take it easy, there are lot of resources online - courses/tutorials etc...